# Processes approximating a reflected brownian motion.

Tags: stochastic-processes, pr.probability

Let $W$ be a standard Brownian Motion.  Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.  Let $X^\epsilon$ be the process which diffuses like $W$ on $(-\epsilon,\infty)$, but when $X^\epsilon$ reaches the level $-\epsilon$, it is immediately brought back to the value zero.  It then diffuses again according to $W$ until hitting $-\epsilon$, and then is brought back to zero, and so forth.  Let $X^0$ be a reflected Brownian Motion (reflected at zero).  Then, as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, in what sense does $X^\epsilon \rightarrow X^0$  Are there any references for this?  I'm also interested in when $W$ is a diffusion.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing some (easily) readable references on this sort of thing too.   One "classic" paper on diffusions with boundary conditions is Stroock and Varadhan's "Diffusions with boundary conditions."

Comment: One thought: the reflected BM is a standard BM plus a local time term at zero.  Using the interpretation of local time in terms of downcrossings should possibly do the trick.

Comment: You're saying that it's the value of the Brownian motion plus the minimal value attained rounded up to the nearest  multiple of $\epsilon$.

That really makes me want to take the limit by deleting the "rounded up" bit. Is that a thing?

Comment: The comments above have the correct idea. We have $X^\epsilon_t=W_t+\epsilon\lfloor\epsilon^{-1}\max\_{s\le t}(-W_s)\rfloor$ which converges uniformly to $W_t-\min\_{s\le t}W_s$. Convergence for this particular process is especially simple.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it should converge in distribution in Skorokhod space D. Martingale problem approach (see the book by Ethier & Kurtz on Markov processes) should work.